# 2 columns window with built-in keyboard

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, on-screen-keyboard

Hi I would like to build an app running on Windows 7 using WPF with 2 columns where one column will be a virtual keyboard or on-screen keyboard (osk) and the other column will be the content of my app.

The keyboard will always appear on every page/window of my app. The keyboard is pretty simple, alphabet and numeric with some buttons such as enter and del. My questions are:

1. How to create 2 columns on a window?
2. Is there a free to use keyboard to attach it to my project? And how can I create my own virtual keyboard?
3. How to make the virtual keyboard always appear on every window?

Answer (score 0):

Building two columns is simple. Add a grid with two `ColumnDefinitions` like this

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Keyboard Grid.Column="0" />
    <CustomContent Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

For the keyboard control, you can have a look at [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32568/A-Touch-Screen-Keyboard-Control-in-WPF)

Also, If you don't want this fully implemented complex thing, you can simply open up the onscreen keyboard by using this -

```
public void CheckKeyboard() 
{
    KeyboardCapabilities keyboardCapabilities = new Windows.Devices.Input.KeyboardCapabilities();
    var isKeyboardPresent = keyboardCapabilities.KeyboardPresent != 0 ? true : false;
    if(!isKeyboardPresent)
        ShowKeyboard();
}

public void ShowKeyboard()
{
    Path(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "osk.exe");
}
```

Comment: I dont to use windows osk, but thx. And how to make the keyboard always appear on every window? Do I have to paste the keyboard code into the keyboard column?

Comment: Please refer to this link - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145579/A-Software-Virtual-Keyboard-for-Your-WPF-Apps
and go to the section - "Using it for your own application". It explains how can you embed it in your application.

Comment: that section gives an example on two different windows, my condition is on one window which split in to two cols

Comment: Please go through the link, it contains all your answers.